# Displaying Toast notifications from Java class

Tags: java, android, class, toast, android-context

I want to create a separate class within my application to handle error reporting and send specific errors to a database. However, I'm unable to figure out what the `Context` should be and how this should be properly coded. I assume it should still be possible, I just need to code it differently, if that is not the case, what is the best solution for me?

```
public class SendError implements Runnable
{

    private String url;

    public SendError(String errors, String form, String database, String SQL)
    {
        url = string;

        Handler handler = new Handler();        
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to do is create one class for my entire application that handles recording of SQL errors when submitting data to the database. The class needs to do 2 simple things. Submit information based on what form, database, time submitted, and the SQL code that created the error. The other thing I would like this class to do is to display a toast giving basic error information back to the user. I have the data submission portion of this worked out properly (hence the reason for the `Runnable`), but am still getting errors for the Toast.

Comment: where do you create this `SendError` object?

Comment: I created it in a completely separate class file.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't do the work in your constructor, this makes your separate class useless.

```
public class SendError implements Runnable
{

    private final Context context;
    private final String url;

    public SendError(Context context, String string) {
        this.context = context;
        this.url = string;
    }

    public void makeToast(String msg, String errors, String form, String database, String SQL) {
       Handler handler = new Handler();        
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your context needs to be the relevant context, from using a `Toast` the `Context` is usually an `Activity` which can take the form of:

- `this` (in an `Activity`)
- `ActivityName.this` (in a inner class of an `Activity`)
- `getActivity` (in a `Fragment` inside an `Activity`)

For example:

```
 new SendError(YourActivity.this, "something").makeToast("Hello", "errors", "form", "database", "sql");
```

Comment: After doing this I still get an error, please check my edit for better explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to pass `Context` in the constructor when you create this class.

I would advise you rethink this class though - it's called "SendError" which sounds like a method name, it implements `Runnable` for some reason, and it's notifying the user with Toasts - sounds like too much for one class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SendError.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```